# Importing json from file into mongodb using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

I have my json_file.json like this:

```
[
{
    "project": "project_1",
    "coord1": 2,
    "coord2": 10,
    "status": "yes",
    "priority": 7
},
{
    "project": "project_2",
    "coord1": 2,
    "coord2": 10,
    "status": "yes",
    "priority": 7
},
{
    "project": "project_3",
    "coord1": 2,
    "coord2": 10,
    "status": "yes",
    "priority": 7
}
]
```

When I run the following command to import this into mongodb:

```
mongoimport --db my_db --collection my_collection --file json_file.json
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?
```

If I add the --jsonArray flag to the command I import like this:

```
imported 3 documents
```

instead of one document with the json format as shown in the original file.

How can I import json into mongodb with the original format in the file shown above?

Comment: The original json format maps to three documents.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Perhaps the following reference from the MongoDB project blog could help you gain insight on how arrays work in Mongo:

https://blog.mlab.com/2013/04/thinking-about-arrays-in-mongodb/

I would frame your import otherwise, and either:

a) import the three different objects separately into the collection as you say, using the --jsonArray flag; or

b) encapsulate the complete array within a single object, for example in this way:

```
{
"mydata": 
    [
    {
          "project": "project_1",
          ...
          "priority": 7
    }
    ]
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the read. Since this json is just supporting D3 visuals, the arrays will never get large. So simply encapsulating the complete array within a single object as you mentioned worked perfectly and is what I chose to do. Should the data need to scale I will look more closely at using separate objects to reduce the amount of data that must be swept through during a query. Cheers.

Answer (score 147):

The `mongoimport` tool has an option:

> `--jsonArray`                    treat input source as a JSON array

Or it is possible to   import from file containing same data format as the result of `db.collection.find()` command. Here is example from [university.mongodb.com](https://university.mongodb.com/) courseware some content from `grades.json`:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "exam", "score" : 54.6535436362647 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb578" }, "student_id" : 0, "type" : "quiz", "score" : 31.95004496742112 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb579" }, "student_id" : 0,       "type" : "homework", "score" : 14.8504576811645 }
```

As you can see, no array used and no comma delimiters between documents either.

I discover, recently, that this complies with [`the JSON Lines text`](http://jsonlines.org/) format.

Like one used in `apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json()` method.

---

Side note:
`$ python -m json.tool --sort-keys --json-lines < data.jsonl`
also can handle this format
see demo and details [here](https://medium.com/@martin.heinz/python-cli-tricks-that-dont-require-any-code-whatsoever-e7bdb9409aeb#847c)

Comment: Thanks even though an old answer, it did fix my current issue

Comment: `--jsonArray` flag did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I faced opposite problem today, my conclusion would be:

If you wish to insert array of JSON objects at once, where each array entry shall be treated as separate dtabase entry, you have two options of syntax:

1. Array of object with valid coma positions & --jsonArray  flag obligatory

   ```
   [
     {obj1},
     {obj2},
     {obj3}
   ]
   ```
2. Use file with basically incorrect JSON formatting (i.e. missing `,` between JSON object instances & without --jsonArray flag

   ```
   {obj1}
   {obj2}
   {obj3}
   ```

If you wish to insert only an array (i.e. array as top-level citizen of your database) I think it's not possible and not valid, because mongoDB by definition supports documents as top-level objects which are mapped to JSON objects afterwards. In other words, you must wrap your array into JSON object as ALAN WARD pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

**Error:**

```
$ ./mongoimport --db bookings --collection user --file user.json

2021-06-12T18:52:13.256+0530    connected to: localhost
2021-06-12T18:52:13.261+0530    Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?
2021-06-12T18:52:13.261+0530    imported 0 documents
```

**Solution:** When your JSON data contain an array of objects then we need to use  **--jsonArray** while import with the command like mentioned below

```
$ ./mongoimport --db bookings --collection user --file user.json --jsonArray
2021-06-12T18:53:44.164+0530    connected to: localhost
2021-06-12T18:53:44.532+0530    imported 414 documents
```