# Failed: line1, column 134: extraneous " in field Error while importing csv file in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, csv

I'm new to `mongodb` and while trying to import  csv file using the syntax below it returns the  error below.The first lines of my csv file is as follows:

Source,"ID","Date","Timestamp","Author","Author ID","Longitude","Latitude","Likes","Comments","Retweets","Text"

Can anyone kindly help me.Thank you in advance !  [error output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ddqS.png)

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongoimport --db mydatabase 
--collection sites --type csv --headerline --file C:\mydata\sample.csv
```

Output Error

> 2016-07-06T16:07:51.395+0200    **Failed: line 1, column 134:
>   extraneous " in field**
>
> 2016-07-06T16:07:51.397+0200    **imported 0 documents**

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like the (first lines of) the csv file might be relevant for answering the question, please add them to the question ("edit")

Comment: Thank you Stefan Hegny! I have added my first line of my csv file.Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is better Convert CSV file into JSON format 
**or**
import JSON instead of CSV.

**To import JSON as collection of objects then**

Example:

JSON1 :

[{"project":"project_1","status":"yes","priority":7},{"project":"project_2","status":"yes","priority":7},{"project":"project_3","status":"yes","priority":7}]

**mongoimport --db myDB--collection myCollection --file battles.json --jsonArray**

Imprort as single object

JSON2 :

[{"mydata":[{"project":"project_1","status":"yes","priority":7},{"project":"project_2","status":"yes","priority":7},{"project":"project_3","status":"yes","priority":7}]}]

mongoimport --db myDB--collection myCollection --file battles.json

Ref:

[Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380751/importing-json-from-file-into-mongodb-using-mongoimport)

[jsonArray import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171622/mongoimport-of-json-file)

[error invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870155/mongodb-mongoimport-error-invalid-character)